# Convert any document, image, text file into PDF

Tags: node.js, pdf, doc

I want to convert any documents or image or text file into PDF for all the OS.

I tried the approach with **[node-msoffice-pdf](https://github.com/skmp/node-msoffice-pdf)**, and its working fine for Windows OS but not working in other OS.

**Question:**

How to convert docs, images, textfile to pdf in nodejs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used wkhtmltopdf from years to manage pdf conversion.

https://github.com/devongovett/node-wkhtmltopdf

You can either render an html file and pass it to the module, or render a pdf directly from an url.

Comment: Okay. I will check it.

Comment: I tried but I am getting this error. "/bin/bash: wkhtmltopdf: command not found". I followed the steps which are mentioned in the git link.

Comment: you have to install the binary of wkhtmltopdf first https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html

Comment: Yes, I tried but still it's not working. And I don't have html files, I have .docx, .xlsx, .pptx, .txt, .png or .jpeg and I want to convert these extensions into pdf.

Comment: try those packages, they seems to don't have windows dependencies : https://www.npmjs.com/package/office-to-pdf https://www.npmjs.com/package/office-converter https://www.npmjs.com/package/office2pdf

Comment: I tried office-to-pdf package and it's working fine to convert docx, xlsx, pptx and txt file into PDF. But can you please help me to convert image into PDF.

Answer (score -2):

If fidelity/conversion quality is important to you, for Word documents (doc/docx) you could try our freemium  https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nativedocuments/docx-wasm which will perform the conversion locally (ie where node is running), without the need to LibreOffice etc.